# Paging integration with Objectbox database in Android

Tags: android, paging, android-architecture-components, objectbox

I want use paging3 from jetpack (Android Architecture Components) with [Objectbox](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java). But have troubles with loading next pages.
When recyclerview scrolled down RemoteMediator doesnt trigger to LoadType.APPEND event. What could be the reasons?

Dependencies:

```
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.7.1"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
```

Paging Source implementation:

```
class CustomPagingSource(

    private val query: Query<Page>

) : PagingSource<Int, Showcase>() {

    private var observer: DataObserver<List<Page>>? = null
    private var subscription: DataSubscription? = null

    init {

        observer = DataObserver<List<Page>> { invalidate() }.also {

            subscription = query.subscribe().onlyChanges().weak().observer(it)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Showcase> {

        val currentPage = params.key ?: 1

        val prevKey = if (currentPage == 1) null else currentPage - 1
        val nextKey = currentPage + 1

        val pages = when (params) {
            is LoadParams.Refresh -> getPages(0, 1)
            is LoadParams.Prepend -> null
            is LoadParams.Append -> getPages(currentPage - 1, 1)
        }

        val items = pages?.map { it.items }?.flatten() ?: emptyList()

        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = items,
            prevKey = prevKey,
            nextKey = nextKey
        )
    }

    override fun invalidate() {
        super.invalidate()
        subscription?.cancel()
        subscription = null
        observer = null
    }

    private fun getPages(startPosition: Int, count: Int): List<Page> =
        this.query.find(startPosition.toLong(), count.toLong())

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Showcase>): Int = 1
}
```

RemoteMediator implementation:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class CustomRemoteMediator(

    private val pullItems: suspend (page: Int, perPage: Int) -> List<Showcase>

) : RemoteMediator<Int, Showcase>() {

    override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, Showcase>): MediatorResult {

        val page = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> 1
            LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val nextKey = state.pages.lastOrNull()?.nextKey
                nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
            }
        }

        val perPage = if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) state.config.initialLoadSize else state.config.pageSize

        return try {
            val items = pullItems(page, perPage)
            val endOfPagination = items.size < perPage

            MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPagination)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Pager creating process:

```
       @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    private fun createPagingSource(): CustomPagingSource = CustomPagingSource(query)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class, FlowPreview::class)
    private val pager by lazy {
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 5,
                initialLoadSize = 5,
                prefetchDistance = 1
            ),
            remoteMediator = CustomRemoteMediator(::pullShowcases),
            pagingSourceFactory = ::createPagingSource
        ).flow
    }
    
    /**
     * pull items from API and put into database
     */
    private suspend fun pullShowcases(page: Int, perPage: Int): List<Showcase> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val showcasesDTO = ApiService.retrofit.getMyShowcases(0.0, 0.0, page, perPage)

        val showcases = showcasesDTO.map {
            Showcase(
                id = it.id,
                title = it.title
            )
        }

        showcaseBox.put(showcases)

        val pageEntity = Page(page.toLong()).also {

            pageBox.attach(it)
            it.items.addAll(showcases)
        }
        pageBox.put(pageEntity)

        return@withContext showcases
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PagingSource` has an `.invalidate()` function you can call to trigger Paging to create a new PagingData / PagingSource pair to reflect changes in your Realm DB.

In your `RemoteMediator` implementation, you should fetch items from network, then write them to db and then invalidate the `PagingSource` before returning `MediatorResult.Success`.

You should set `endOfPaginationReached` to `true` from `MediatorResult`, if there were no updates to your db and you therefore don't expect to invalidate.

Btw, Room automatically handles this in its `PagingSource` implementation, so you may want to look into whether Realm offers some callbacks your `PagingSource` can listen to or you may need to to keep track yourself.

EDIT: Root cause for missing remote APPEND call was not setting `nextKey` to `null` eventually.

Comment: ty for answer
Can you provide any sample how to invalidate PagingSource in a right way?

Comment: You just need to call PagingSource.invalidate(). I'm not that familiar with Realm, so they might have some helpful APIs, but an easy way to track yourself is to pass your PagingSourceFactory through to RemoteMediator and add a function in it to invalidate the current PagingSource. I would try to see if Realm has some kind of callback you can take advantage of though. Then it would be as simple as registering the callback in your PagingSource

Comment: but docs says that Mediator.Success automatically should trigger paging source invalidation

Comment: RemoteMediator.Success can't handle invalidation for you as it's possible to return Success before the backing dataset + invalidate happens, so you need to invalidate manually yourself. If you're able to point to me the place in the docs you found this, it would be great so I can fix them!

Comment: hello. have another trouble =) can you check it again?

Comment: What's the issue you're running into?

Comment: i updated my topic, cant load next pages. cant understand why remote mediator didnt trigger to APPEND events when recycler view scrolling down.

Comment: You need to call PagingSource.invalidate after writing the fetched items to db from RemoteMediator. This is how Pager knows to create a new PagingSource / PagingData pair to load from the updated data and throw away the old state

Comment: i did it, look at my PagingSource implementation on init block. when data in database changed invalidate invoked.

Comment: Looks like you never set `prevKey` or `nextKey` to null in `PagingSource`, so Paging never realizes you're out of pages to load and thus never triggers `RemoteMediator`. Something like `prevKey = if (items.isEmpty()) null else prevKey` starts triggering remote `APPEND` correctly for me.